# Python - Add to a dictionary using a string

Tags: python, dictionary

[Python 3.4.2]
I know this question sounds ridiculous, but I can't figure out where I'm messing up. I'm trying to add keys and values to a dictionary by using strings instead of quoted text. So instead of this,

```
dict['key'] = value
```

this:

```
dict[key] = value
```

When I run the command above, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I think Python is thinking that I'm trying to create a string, not add to a dictionary. I'm guessing I'm using the wrong syntax. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
dict[string_for_key][string_for_value] = string_for_deeper_value
```

I want this^ command to do this:

```
dict = {string_for_key: string_for_value: string_for_deeper_value}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I should probably give some more context. I'm:

1. creating one dictionary
2. creating a copy of it *(because I need to edit the dictionary while iterating through it)*
3. iterating through the first dictionary while running some queries
4. *trying* to assign a query's result as a value for each "key: value" in the dictionary.

Here's a picture to show what I mean:

key: value: query_as_new_value

-----EDIT-----

Sorry, I should have clarified: the dictionary's name is not actually 'dict'; I called it 'dict' in my question to show that it was a dictionary.

-----EDIT-----

I'll just post the whole process I'm writing in my script. The error occurs during the last command of the function. Commented out at the very bottom are some other things I've tried.

```
from collections import defaultdict

global query_line, pericope_p, pericope_f, pericope_e, pericope_g


def _pre_query(self, typ):
    with open(self) as f:
        i = 1
        for line in f:
            if i == query_line:
                break
            i += 1
        target = repr(line.strip())
    ###skipping some code
    pericope_dict_post[self][typ] = line.strip()
    #^Outputs error TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
    return


pericope_dict_pre = {'pericope-p.txt': 'pericope_p',
                     'pericope-f.txt': 'pericope_f',
                     'pericope-e.txt': 'pericope_e',
                     'pericope-g.txt': 'pericope_g'}
pericope_dict_post = defaultdict(dict)
#pericope_dict_post = defaultdict(list)
#pericope_dict_post = {}
for key, value in pericope_dict_pre.items():
    pericope_dict_post[key] = value
        #^Works
    #pericope_dict_post.update({key: value})
        #^Also works
    #pericope_dict_post.append(key)
        #^AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
    #pericope_dict_post[key].append(value)
        #^AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
    _pre_query(key, value)
```

-----FINAL EDIT-----

`Matthias` helped me figure it out, although `acushner` had the solution too. I was trying to make the dictionary three "levels" deep, but Python dictionaries cannot work this way. Instead, I needed to create a nested dictionary. To use an illustration, I was trying to do `{key: value: value}` when I needed to do `{key: {key: value}}`.

To apply this to my code, I need to create the [second] dictionary with all three strings at once. So instead of this:

```
my_dict[key] = value1
my_dict[key][value1] = value2
```

I need to do this:

```
my_dict[key][value1] = value2
```

Thanks a ton for all your help guys!

Comment: if `key` is not defined before you will get error

Comment: Yeah, it's already defined. All three strings (`string_for_key`, `string_for_value`, and `string_for_deeper_value`) are already defined. The dictionary already contains the key pointed to by `string_for_key` and the value pointed to by `string_for_key`. I'm trying to insert `string_for_deeper_value` into the dictionary as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a dictionary that expands by itself (Python 3 required).

```
class AutoTree(dict):
"""Dictionary with unlimited levels"""

     def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value
```

Use it like this.

```
data = AutoTree()
data['a']['b'] = 'foo'
print(data)
```

Result

```
{'a': {'b': 'foo'}}
```

Now I'm going to explain your problem with the message `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`.

This code will work

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(dict)
data['a']['b'] = 'c'
```

`data['a']` doesn't exist, so the default value `dict` is used. Now `data['a']` is a `dict` and this dictionary gets a new value with the key `'b'` and the value `'c'`.

This code won't work

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(dict)
data['a'] = 'c'
data['a']['b'] = 'c'
```

The value of `data['a']` is defined as the string `'c'`. Now you can only perform string operations with `data['a']`. You can't use it as a dictionary now and that's why `data['a']['b'] = 'c'` fails.

Comment: you don't even need a class for that. `dd = lambda: defaultdict(dd)`

Comment: @acushner: I upvoted your answer because that ist what I would do. My code is just a part from a more complex class and might come handy sometimes.

Comment: Each of the `AutoTree` and `dd = lambda: defaultdict(dd)` options still give me `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`. Thanks for all the help though guys. I think the problem is that I'm using a string instead of text on the right hand side of the equation. So `my_dict[key][value] = string` instead of `my_dict[key][value] = 'text'`

Comment: that is not it. at all. either `my_dict` is a `list` or `my_dict[key]` is a `list`. that is your problem.

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23: The error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` has nothing to with the dictionary code. There is no list involved.

Comment: Wow sorry my brain's a little fried right now. I meant `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23: I tried to explain it in my post. When you use `pericope_dict_post[key] = value` then `pericope_dict_post[key]` is fixed. It won't change to be a dictionary later, so `pericope_dict_post[self][typ] = line.strip()` can't work.

Comment: Oh!!! I think I've got it. I was trying to create `{key: value: value}` when I needed to create `{key: {key: value}}`. Is that it? Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Yep. That's it. Glad we could find the problem. (Obligatory begging: Would you mind accepting my answer?) ;-)

Comment: Lol I didn't even know how to do that. Can you tell I'm new to the site? :P I figured it out though. Thanks again!

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23, attention to detail is insanely important in coding, and you could have saved yourself so much time if you just did exactly what was in both Matthias' and my answers. just a hint for dealing with future problems. because details matter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that. :) It never crossed my mind that I wouldn't be able to do it in steps like I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

first, do not use `dict` as your variable name as it shadows the built-in of the same name.

second, all you want is a nested dictionary, no?

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
d[string_for_key][string_for_value] = 'snth'
```

another way, as @Matthias suggested, is to create a bottomless dictionary:

```
dd = lambda: defaultdict(dd)
d = dd()
d[string_for_key][string_for_value] = 'snth'
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this, but instead of `d[string_for_key][string_for_value] = 'snth'` I'm using `d[string_for_key][string_for_value] = snth`. It gives me the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: you are creating a list somewhere. check the type of your objects

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`. I did this in another comment too. :S

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> key = 'a'               # if key is not defined before it will raise NameError
>>> my_dict[key] = [1]
>>> my_dict[key].append(2)
>>> my_dict
{'a': [1, 2]}
```

Note: `dict` is inbuilt don't use it as variable name

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this, but I get the error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: Sure, I added some of my script into my original question.